# Insert query in while loop in a function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to write a SQL function that should return temp table with 2 columns. But I want to use `while` loop. I want to insert multiple insert queries to temp table.
But when I am using insert query in while loop in SQL function, it is giving the empty result. Following is my case.
Code something like this:

```
create function dbo.fn_GetSubTree1(@type as Varchar(50)) 
returns @tree table
(sizename Varchar(9) not null,shiptotal int)
as
BEGIN
Declare @maxsize int;
Declare @counter int=0;
   WHILE @counter < 24
BEGIN
        insert into @tree(sizename,shiptotal) select s.size,s.shp from style st join scale s on st.scale=s.scale and s.nrfkey='' and s.prepak=''
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END 
return 
End
```

Comment: Tag our question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `WHILE @counter < 24`, but never initialise the counter to any value.

The line `DECLARE @counter INT;` doesn't initialise the variable to `0`, it initialises it to `NULL`.  Which means your first loop is checking `NULL < 24` which isn't `TRUE`.

Try this...

```
Declare @counter int = 0;
...
WHILE @counter < 24
BEGIN
    ...
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

You also seem to have other issues, such as `select ' + @Size + ','+@Shp + ' from ...` making no apparent sense.

***EDIT:***

I recommend starting with making a simple case work and building it up from there.  If it ever stops working, the problem is what ever you last changed.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_GetSubTree1(
   @type AS NVARCHAR(50)
) 
RETURNS @tree TABLE (
   sizename  NVARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
   shiptotal INT
)
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @counter INT = 0;
   WHILE (@counter < 24)
   BEGIN
      INSERT INTO
         @tree(
            sizename,
            shiptotal
         )
      VALUES (
         'Test',
         @counter
      )

      SET @counter = @counter + 1;
   END

   RETURN
END
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried with your answer. But still i didn't get any result. Means no results.

Comment: @user1498942 - Consider whether your join is at fault.  Or better still start with a simple case and then build it up.  I'll add an example to the question.

Comment: I have modified the code. Please verify once. Still i am not getting results. Please help.

Comment: I already suggested considering whether the join is at fault.  Have you tested whether `select s.size,s.shp from style st join scale s on st.scale=s.scale and s.nrfkey='' and s.prepak=''` actually gives any rows?  See my edit and try that, as it doesn't rely on your join.  If that works, you can incrementally add parts to your code.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with another table then it is working fine. But what i provided in the code not giving the result. I will check that table. Thank you for your support

Comment: Yes. You are right it is problem with last two conditions in join. Now it is working fine to me.

Comment: Hi, Here i have one more question. I have to use dynamic column names that is the reason in my earlier code i have use 'size'....... In my table i have columns like size0,size1....size24. So instead of writing 24 queries. I need to write in a loop. I want the result as 24 rows. Can you help. How to use dynamic column in this case.

Comment: You need to ask a whole new question for that